# stack smashing detected por inicializar array en c

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual estoy atascado, tengo un error que no llego a comprender.
Tengo la siguiente estructura en game.c

```
struct _Game
{
  Player *player;
  Enemy *enemy;
  Object *objects[MAX_SPACES];
  Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
  Link *links[MAX_SPACES];
  T_Command last_cmd;
  char descr[MAX_WORD];
};
```

y en la siguiente función inicializo todo:

```
STATUS game_create(Game *game)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SPACES; i++)
  {
    game->spaces[i] = NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SPACES; i++)
  {
    game->objects[i] = NULL;
  }
  game->descr[0] = '\0';
  
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SPACES; i++)
  {
    game->links[i] = NULL;
  }
  game->enemy = NULL;
  game->player = NULL;
  game->last_cmd = NO_CMD;

  return OK;
}
```

El problema está en los links, antes todo funcionaba OK pero desde que simplemente inicializo los links a NULL la memoria peta y sale stack smashing detected. Antes tenía funciones implementadas de link y tal pero al cambiar cosas me he dado cuenta que simplemente por inicializar el link a NULL tengo problemas graves en memoria, ¿que puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: Estás haciendo que todos los elementos del array apunten a `NULL`. Con que declares que el primer elemento apunte a `NULL` es suficiente, ya que luego recorrerás el array desplazando el puntero y puedes hacer la típica comprobación al inicio de comprobar si tu variable es distinto a NULL

Comment: ¿En algún momento añades objetos a esos arrays? ¿De qué manera los añades? Cuando estás recorriendo esos arrays para hacer algo ... ¿Compruebas si los elementos apuntan o no a NULL antes de intentar acceder a su contenido?